# S3 Upload Multiple images in loop with Amazon IOS Sdk and get public url's

Tags: ios

How to upload Multiple images file on S3 with Amazon IOS Sdk v2 or v1. And get back there public url and save to Nsarray.

Check below my code to upload a single Image. However, now I want to upload Multiple Images at a time one after other

Can any one help me please.
Thanks in advance

```
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = @"myBucket";
uploadRequest.key = @"imag.png";
uploadRequest.body = imagefileUrl;
uploadRequest.ACL=AWSS3BucketCannedACLPublicRead;

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor]

  withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
  if (task.error) {
     if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain])
     {
         switch (task.error.code)
         {
                case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                break;

                default:
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                        break;
          }
      } else {
               // Unknown error.
                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
              }
  }
  if (task.result) {
      AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutput = task.result;
        // The file uploaded successfully.
   }
     return nil;
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired functionality by using a self calling method as below.

```
@property int counter;


_counter = 0;// set this from where you are calling this method.
-(void)uploadToS3FromUploadQueue{
   //upload
NSArray *paths = arrayContainglocalPathsOfYourFilesToUpload;
NSString * documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *mediaDocumentDirectoryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsPath];
[self uploadTransferManagerBlockWithKey:observationModel.actualname andBody:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:mediaDocumentDirectoryPath] ofBaseModel:baseModel];
}
-(void)uploadTransferManagerBlockWithKey:(NSString *)key andBody:(NSURL
*)objectURL ofBaseModel:(BaseModel *)baseModel{
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName;
uploadRequest.key = key;
uploadRequest.body = objectURL;
uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPublicRead;
[[_transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                    withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                                                        if (task.error) {


                                                            if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                                                                switch (task.error.code) {

                                                                    case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                                                                        break;
                                                                    case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                                                                        break;

                                                                    default:
                                                                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);

                                                                        break;
                                                                }
                                                            } else {
                                                                // Unknown error.
                                                                NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                            }
                                                            // 

                                                            [uploadRequest cancel];
                                                            [_transferManager cancelAll];



                                                            counter = 0;



                                                                [self uploadToS3FromUploadQueue];
                                                            }



                                                        }

                                                        if (task.result) {
                                                            AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutput = task.result;
                                                             NSLog(@"Result Upload: %@", uploadOutput);
                                                            if (yourArrayContainingObject.count-1 == _counter) {
//Upload Completed
                                                            }
                                                            else{
                                                                _counter++;
                                                                [self uploadToS3FromUploadQueue];
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        return nil;
                                                    }];
}
```

i wrote this code in hurry but will give you a perfect idea.
Good Luck